# Custom error message for `requiredIf` validation in laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

I'm working on a Laravel 5.8 project and trying to show custom validation messages for a validation which uses the `requiredIf` validation rule.

Here is how I have it set up:

```
$validation = Validator::make(
    $request->all(),
    [
        ...
        'sum' => [
            Rule::requiredIf(function() use ($request){
                $model = Model::find($request->id);
                return $model->is_special; //returns a boolean value
            }),
            'numeric'
        ],
        ...
    ],
    [
        ...
        'sum.required_if' => 'This cannot be blank',
        'sum.numeric' => 'Must use a number here',
        ...
    ]
);
```

Now the validation is working correctly and the custom message for the `numeric` validation shows as should, but the message I get for the `requiredIf()` method is Laravel's default error message.

I also tried using `'sum.requiredIf' => '...'` but that didn't work either and can't seem to find any documentation or example for this scenario.

Comment: `sum.required_if` should work. Try removing the `numeric` validation and then check

Comment: @ascsoftw I have tried both with and without the numeric validation. They both work. The validation part works... its just the custom error message that doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was tinkering with this for a while and noticed that for this to work I needed to define

`'sum.required' => 'This cannot be blank'`

and not `'sum.required_if' => 'This cannot be blank',`.

Not sure if this is expected behavior or just a workaround but my deduction is that with the callback `Rule::requiredIf(function() use ($request){...})` the parameters `:other` and `:value` are not passed so it falls back onto `required` messaging and I guess this makes sense since `required_if` and `required` would not be used on the same `:attribute`.

Hope this helps anyone who comes across this problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, [create a rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules) name isSpecial or whatever

```
php artisan make:rule isSpecial
```

Go to App\Rules\isSpecial.php

```
    private $id;

    public function __construct($id) // pass id or what you need
    {
        //
        $this->id=$id;
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value) // customize your rules here
    {
        //
        return Model::find($request->id)->is_special;
    }


    public function message() // here is answer for your question
    {
        return 'The validation error message.'; // your message
    }
```

in your controller

```
 use App\Rules\isSpecial;

  \Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'sum' => new isSpecial() ,
  ])->validate();
```

another idea  :

[Specifying Custom Messages In Language Files](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#localization)
In most cases, you will probably specify your custom messages in a language file instead of passing them directly to the Validator. To do so, add your messages to custom array in the resources/lang/xx/validation.php language file.

```
'custom' => [
    'email' => [
        'required' => 'We need to know your e-mail address!',
    ],
],
```

Simple notice:
- I suggest using [HTTP Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests) instead use validation in your controller and function direct

Comment: Thanks @Mahmoud, I understand your logic and appreciate the suggestion but the question was intended to find a way to add a custom message to Laravel's `required_if` validation (see https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-required-if)

Comment: @natral Yes I know but I search about this point I can't find any references or documentation on how to do this? and I access to source code Illuminate\Validation\Rules\RequiredIf.php I didn't found any way to print customize message but I will try again tomorrow to find a way:).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like as of Laravel 8, using required_if works as expected, and alternatively will not fall back on required as mentioned previously:

`'sum.required_if' => 'This cannot be blank',`

Comment: I spent a lot of time trying to find a way to make it work, so ridiculous that this is not documented anywhere. thanks for your correct answer.